# JMETER - Extractor Expressão Regular (regex)

Tags: regex, jmeter

Boa tarde,
Estou com a seguinte dificuldade no JMETER:

"presignedUrlRequest": "https://fng-contratos-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/d29e66bc-0446-427a-b775-1e6337a91ac0?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEBoaDLh4z888ggnOg%2B8QvCKEAncUSZst5G5HYDWQwd9OssIBIfnjIijL%2FXNo2BVv9UWYFaVeYzYFIHe37185mx5t728"

Preciso extrair todo o link, mas em 3 partes.
1 com apenas o https. A segunda com o fng-contratos-dev.s3.amazonaws.com. E a terceira a partir do d29e66....

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Apesar de ser possível fazer com regex, não acho que seja o melhor jeito (regex é legal, [mas nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)).
Minha sugestão é que você use a classe `java.net.URL`, que representa uma URL (justamente o que sua `String` é): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo retorno!
Vou verificar e entender. No entanto, você saberia informar sobre o regex nessa situação?

Comment: Creio que uma busca no google por "regex URL" deve trazer várias opções - e talvez aqui mesmo nesse site deva ter alguma pergunta relacionada (desculpe, não pesquisei, mas deve ter sim pq não é um assunto novo e alguém já deve ter perguntado). Mas essas regex geralmente são tão complicadas que eu acho mais simples usar a classe `URL` mesmo  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionar um [Extrator de expressão regular](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

use a seguinte configuração em seu extrator de expressões regulares.

```
Field to Check : URL

Name of Created Variable : Value

Regular Expression : (.+?):\/\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\?X-Amz

Template : $1$2$3$

Match no:  1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

This will extract all 3 required values on a single go and saves these values in variables `Value_g1, Value_g2, Value_g3`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode usar $ {Value_g1} / $ {Value_g2 / Value_g3} para substituir valores

Mais Informações

[Extratores de expressão regular](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, @Rohit.
Me serviu bastante.